# Network Failures (software tester)

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I have one network with - / +50 computer.

Lan and last days, has Apparent fail. Don't make any change the network.

Apparent fail moments by the network, and does not understand why.

That is there any software can analyze the network failures.

Some troubleshooting I've done:
Changed the switch for better (3com); Passed-the new cable to the router.

edit:
Example: I'm doing ping to our internal server, "requests timed out"
The share folder takes long to open file (due to network outages)
We lost our connection to the internal webserver.

But only in a specific network part in the other half of all network works to 100%

Comment: You will have to provide more information in order for us to help you.

Comment: Failed how? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I assume you're on a domain? Or work group?

Comment: Example: I'm doing ping to our internal server, "requests timed out"
The share folder takes long to open file (due to network outages)
We lost our connection to the internal webserver.

But only in a specific network part in the other half of all network works to 100%

Comment: Yes i'm on domain.

Comment: Okay, so when `ping` fails, is the cable lit up on both ends? Do you get a valid IP address assigned? Does your ARP table contain the correct hardware address of the machine you are trying to `ping`? You need to keep troubleshooting until you find the very first thing that doesn't work.

Comment: The question about cable lit'm going to check this.
But the ping is the example. the connection fail is a stupid event is not the time, nor for large periods of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild shot sounds a bit like you have a dns lookup issue.. check your DNS forward and reverse lookups on you domain controller. You may have a device or two with the same or more than one IP address.